# Отсортировать массивы от большему к меньшему PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Необходимо отсортировать массивы от большему к меньшему (за элементом likes_count)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["likes_count"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["likes_count"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте функцию uasort() *(или usort() - если не нужно сохранять связь между ключами)*:

```
$arr = [
    [
        "likes_count"=>1
    ],
    [
        "likes_count"=>5
    ],
    [
        "likes_count"=>10
    ]
];

uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;
});

var_dump($arr);
```

Если вы используете PHP>=7, то есть альтернативный вариант с оператором `<=>`:

```
$arr = [
    [
        "likes_count"=>1
    ],
    [
        "likes_count"=>5
    ],
    [
        "likes_count"=>10
    ]
];

uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
    return $b <=> $a;
});

var_dump($arr);
```

---

UPD: Или использовать `array_multisort()`:

```
$arr = [
    [
        "gifsurl"=>"vk.com/…;",
        "texts"=>"Текст",
        "likes_count"=>1
    ],
    [
        "gifsurl"=>"vk.com/…;",
        "texts"=>"Текст",
        "likes_count"=>5
    ],
    [
        "gifsurl"=>"vk.com/…;",
        "texts"=>"Текст",
        "likes_count"=>287
    ],
];

$likes_count = array_column($arr, 'likes_count');
array_multisort($likes_count, SORT_DESC, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: А если в массиве кроме likes_count есть и другие ключи с элементами?

Comment: array(15) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["gifsurl"]=>
    string(128) "https://vk.com/doc41100057_472489027?hash=992442a6abda51afd5&dl=GE2DIMRTG44TIMA:1535140441:9c983f0706b2922512&api=1&no_preview=1"
    ["texts"]=>
    string(48) "Текст"
    ["likes_count"]=>
    int(287)
  }}

Comment: @CoffeeinTime я подкорректировал свой ответ. В следующий раз в пост с вопросом записывайте корректную структуру массива.